# How to trigger cancel button in UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

How to trigger programmatically cancel button in UISearchBar, like if you have tapped cancel button?

I have a UISearchBar in the top of a UITableView and after a search, when someone select a row, I want to trigger programmatically cancel button in the UISearchBar?

**EDIT:** Without user interaction.

Comment: Do you have a search display controller?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For a view controller using a search display controller, you can set

```
self.searchDisplayController.active = NO;
// or:
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

to dismiss the search interface.

Comment: Aeew, thanks!! it works! I just don't know why I got down votes , thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 31):

For the new [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html) (introduced in 2014 with iOS 8) you can call:

```
[self.searchController setActive:FALSE];
```

or

```
self.searchController.active = FALSE;
```

(No flag for animation, I've found it always animates.)

Comment: I tried the code above. It seems to be working in a demo I found, but doesn't seems to be working in my code, Do you have any idea? currently using self.searchDisplayController?.setActive(false, animated: true) to dismiss the Search Controller, but I fear because its a deprecated code.

Comment: @vinbhai4u hard to tell with your small comment.  You should submit a new question where you explain things in more detail.

Comment: If you don't want animation, you can wrap it in a UIView.performWithoutAnimation block.

Answer (score 29):

You need to implement the `UISearchBarDelegate`.  Once you've done that, use:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

> Tells the delegate that the cancel button was tapped.

Then use:

```
[self searchBarCancelButtonClicked:yourSearchBar];
```

Comment: No, I need to do it programmatically. without user interaction.

Comment: With Swift

self.searchBarCancelButtonClicked(YourSearchBar)

Answer (score 6):

As for iOS 8, `UISearchController` is used, to achieve the cancel button action programmatically, 
Use:

```
[self.searchController setActive:NO];
```

Comment: Yes. This one does triggering search cancel search mode. In view disappear event, this call is critical to avoid memory leak when the view is in searching mode. Otherwise, the view would not be released from memory.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 4.2 version you can write as the following code:

```
searchController?.isActive = false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = false // above iOS 8.0
// or:    
self.searchDisplayController.active = NO; // was deprecated in iOS 8.0
// or:
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES]; // Obejective-C
```

These are some of the variants that accomplish the mentioned task